# What is the cause of Letitia James’s “civil claim” against trump?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, president, new-york-city, civil

It’s confusing to me because her standing seems to derive from her position as attorney general, and yet this is a position that is meant as I had understood to prosecute crimes, not civil matters. So what is the essence of the civil dispute at the heart of the case?

Answer (score 2):

The Attorney General of New York, and of US states in general, takes all kinds of legal action on behalf of their state. The AG is generally not involved in initial prosecution of criminal matters, but is frequently involved in civil suits alleging that their state has been harmed. For example, yesterday a dozen states filed a lawsuit against Meta for harming children, and that included New York.

I don't know which lawsuit you are referring to, but one example is her lawsuit against Trump for fraud: the details are [here](https://ag.ny.gov/sites/default/files/tto_complaint.pdf).

Comment: Civil lawsuit for harming children? And what is the case against trump actually for, if the gain was from banks that gave loans rather than from her state?

Comment: Yes, civil lawsuit for harming children.

Comment: This article might be informative to you: https://apnews.com/article/trump-fraud-new-york-letitia-james-lawsuit-a3a2c2569440c24bd5c5262103cb8390

Comment: @Seekinganswers If you read the filing linked in the answer you'll see that they are charging under [New York Executive Law § 63(12)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Executive_Law_§_63(12)#:~:text=Due%20to%20its%20broad%20definitions,investigation%20of%20The%20Trump%20Organization.). This gives the AG the power to investigate civil fraud.